# Отложенная загрузка в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Разбираюсь с этим фреймворком. 
Не могу понять как правильно сделать отложенную загрузку.

Допустим есть Мероприятия и их цены.
2 модели: `Sittings` и `SittingsPrices`

Sittings:

```
public function getSittingsPrices(){
    return $this->hasMany(SittingsPrices::className(),['sitting_id' => 'id']);
}
```

SittingsPrices:

`public function getSitting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Sittings::className(), ['id' => 'sitting_id']);
    }`

Делаю:

`$event = Sittings::findOne($id);
$prices = $event->sittingsPrices;`

Все прекрасно работает. 
Однако я хочу выбрать не все записи в prices, а с определенными условиями.

Допустим

`$prices = $event->sittingsPrices->where(['true'=>'1'])`

Получаю ошибку: `Call to a member function where() on a non-object`

Comment: `$prices = $event->getSittingsPrices()->where...`

Answer (score 0):

теоретически попробую , вы там проверьте

Когда вы задаете условие для findOne()  оно задается внутри скобок
к примеру

```
$model->findOne(['doctor' => $id, 'room_category' => $this->room_name]);
```

а вы в эвентс закидываете `findOne` и пытаетесь к нему `where` .

( и лучше делать вот так `find()->where()->limit(1)->one();`) потому что у фреймворка нет встроенного `limit`

и попробуйте вот так `getSittingsPrices()->where` ( исходя из вашей ошибки )